# php zend framework 1 netbeans xdebug

Tags: php, macos, zend-framework, netbeans, xdebug

I work in a Mac (OSX 10.10.3 Yosemite), with Bitnami XAMPP 5.6.3, Netbeans 7.3.1, and the xdebug configuration showed down. With my "normal" PHP projects everything works fine, but now I am trying to learn Zend Framework, and I have installed ZendFramework-1.12.17, for which I reached to obtain a "Hello world" in a PHP 5.3 project, but when I try to debug the same project, the status bar of the debbuger remains "Waiting for connection netbeans-xdebug" forever.

I searched the web, but I think that this is so specific case that I could only find an answer on this forum recomending to install XAMPP 1.7.0 :( very old version) that has  Zend Extension Manager, something that 1) doubt it can work with my configuration and 2) can affect my other projects.

Can someone help me please? Thank you and best regards.

In php.ini:

```
zend_extension = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Comment: When you run debug, you browser should be open you project with xdebug key, and netbins get connect to your server.

Comment: That is working without Zend Framework, but not with Zend Framework